# Setting the max http connections on `[NSURLSession backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier]` is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I'm trying to create a simple downloader for our app. The app will download large files from our server (at least 100 MB per file), so I want to implement a downloader that will work even if the app is inactive.

I'm using `NSURLSession` to handle this requests. Here's how I initialised the session:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSURLSession *downloadSession;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   // Initialise the session
   NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSession backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier: @"backgroundSessionIdentifier"];
   [sessionConfig setHTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost:10];

   _downloadSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: sessionConfig delegate: self delegateQueue: nil];
}
```

I also implement the `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` function below to check the progress of each download:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
   float totalProgress = (float)totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
   NSLog(@"URL: %@, progress: %f", downloadTask.originalRequest.URL.absoluteString, totalProgress);
}
```

I have a `UICollectionView` and each cell has a button that will create a download task when tapped:

```
// A delegate function of the custom UICollectionViewCell
- (void)beginDownloadAtIndex:(NSInteger)fileIndex {
    NSString *fileURL = [self.urls objectAtIndex: fileIndex];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [self.downloadSession downloadTaskWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: fileURL]];
    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

Now say that I have 10 items in the `UICollectionView`. I set the `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` to 10 so that I can download them simultaneously.

What happens is that the first 3 download tasks I created will begin downloading simultaneously, but the other 7 will not. When one of the first 3 download tasks is complete, one of the "dormant" download task will then begin downloading.

I may be doing something wrong because when I tried using the default session configuration `[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]`, all 10 download tasks will begin downloading simultaneously.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone can help me to identify what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background sessions happen out of process in a separate background daemon.  It seems very likely that Apple deliberately limited the ability to change that parameter to prevent an unusually high number of transfers from being in flight while your app isn't running.

You can file a bug with Apple, but I suspect that they'll send it back as "Behaves correctly".

That said, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by using a large number of parallel downloads.  Barring unusually high packet loss or deliberate throttling by the ISP (e.g. burst mode), there shouldn't be much difference between running ten large downloads three at a time and running them ten at a time, on average.

Comment: It's not really a big problem if this is the normal behaviour. I just thought that I might be doing something wrong because I've seen projects that use NSURLSession backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier for downloading multiple files and they all begin downloading simultaneously. This project right here is an example: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: It *might* be more willing to do so if you set `shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode`, but I'm not sure.  One other trick is that all of the concurrency limits are per-session, IIRC, so if you create separate background sessions for each request... kind of icky, but it will probably get the result you want.  Whether it is worth doing or not, I couldn't say.  :-D

Comment: Seems like it really restricts the connections to 4 max, and honestly since it's not a big problem I'll leave it as it is. I'll mark your answer as correct since you gave a very reasonable answer to my question. Thanks for helping!